# Can't find my fingerprint device on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, fingerprint-reader

I can't find my fingerprint device when I list the available devices connected to the USB hub via the below command:

```
lsusb
```

However, the device was working fine when I was using Windows 11 on the same laptop (DELL Latitude 5420).

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it show up if you connect it directly to a PC. Beware that it can be shown without syaing that it is a fingerprint scanner. You'd better post the output to your question. And not all fingerprint scanners are supported.

Comment: Just because it works with Windows, it doesn't mean it works with Linux, too. If there is no kernel module supporting your fingerprint reader, Ubuntu won't detect it.